# Is there a way on R to combine rows to make a total/average?

Tags: r, concatenation, rows

I have a big df which looks like this:

```
Name      Year    Runs   Average
J. Doe    2016    432    44.5
J. Doe    2017    325    37.4
J. Bloggs 2016    289    54.3
```

I want to concatenate rows so that I can make a total for each name, rather than split by year. Some columns e.g. Runs would need to be summed and others e.g. Average would need other formulae dependent on other columns. The df is too big to do it manually, so is there a function I can use to combine these rows whenever there is a repeated name?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(sum_of_runs = sum(Runs),
            average_of_column_x = mean(column_x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I had a similar solution, but deleted my answer. If you want to maintain the other columns: `df %>%  group_by(Name) %>%  mutate(Runs = sum(Runs), Overall_Avg = mean(Average))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `sum` `Runs` column and take `mean` of `Average` column for each unique value in  `Name`, using `data.table` you can do :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Runs = sum(Runs), Avg = mean(Average)), Name]

#       Name Runs  Avg
#1:    J.Doe  757 41.0
#2: J.Bloggs  289 54.3
```

Add `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum` and `mean` functions if you have `NA` values.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("J.Doe", "J.Doe", "J.Bloggs"), Year = c(2016L, 
2017L, 2016L), Runs = c(432L, 325L, 289L), Average = c(44.5, 
37.4, 54.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```